# UILabel blur only text

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uilabel, blur

I'm trying to blur the text of a label that I create programmatically, I've been able to apply the blur, but only to the label itself, leaving the text readable and blurying only the background behind the label.

Is there any way to blur only the text?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Heres my code till now:

```
UILabel *lblVericalName = 
    [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-95, 
                                             _viewVerticalStick.frame.size.height-120,
                                             200,
                                             20)];
lblVericalName.tag = [tarefaDiaArray.idTarefaDia integerValue];
lblVericalName.text = tarefaDiaArray.nomeTarefa;

lblVericalName.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI+89.55 );

UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = 
    [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

blurEffectView.frame = lblVericalName.bounds;

blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


[viewStickBackground addSubview:lblVericalName];

if ([tarefaDiaArray.tarefaPremium intValue] ==1) {
    //[viewStickBackground addSubview:blurEffectView];
    [lblVericalName addSubview:blurEffectView];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

[image: Blurred text]

**UPDATE**

I've made some progress, now I have this:

[image: my image]

and I need to make it look like this:

[image: what i want]

here is the code that i'm using:

lblNomeVertical.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.494 green:0.494 blue:0.494 alpha:0.8];

```
lblNomeVertical.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1.1); 
lblNomeVertical.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.827 green:0.827 blue:0.827 alpha:1].CGColor; 
lblNomeVertical.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
lblNomeVertical.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
```

Comment: You have not shown what you're actually doing. Show it.

Comment: Please explain what your current code does and why it's not satisfactory for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I've added a image of what happens. I need the text to be blurred (defocused) but not all the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a label, use a drawing. In code, draw the text yourself and blur it yourself (e.g. with a box blur or a gaussian blur CIFilter). Now just place that drawing in front of your background. In that way, I was able to achieve this, which seems to be the sort of thing you are after (of course it can be more blurry if you want):

[image]

Comment: Im having trouble using the drawing, but I now understand that this is the way to go. I just need to read some documentation now. Thanks